# Scoped web services

Tags: java, web-services, web

The official Axis manual states that:

> Scoped Services
>
> Axis supports scoping service objects (the actual Java objects which
>   implement your methods) three ways. "Request" scope, the default, will
>   create a new object each time a SOAP request comes in for your
>   service. "Application" scope will create a singleton shared object to
>   service all requests. "Session" scope will create a new object for
>   each session-enabled client who accesses your service. To specify the
>   scope option, you add a  to your service like this (where
>   "value" is request, session, or application):

Is there any way to specify that using annotation defined by the standard JAX-WS ?

Comment: A search on this give me these results: https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/http-session-scope/ https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/thread-scope/ and by reading those resources, the default scope for JAX-WS beans is Application.

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-WS don't provide this out-of-the-box. There is JAX-WS commons, where you can find these annotations:

- [`@HttpSessionScope`](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/http-session-scope/) that allows the creation of an instance of the service class per session. (Equivalent of Session scope).
- [`@ThreadScope`](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/thread-scope/) that allows the creation of an instance of the service class per each thread request. (Equivalent of Request scope). Note that these beans are reused among requests.

By default, the service class is created per application context.

Comment: so each framework implementing JAX-WS is to be given this kind of configuration information in a non standard way,if I understand correctly ?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. As noted in my answer, these annotations are not part of JAX-WS, but provided as extensions.

Comment: The same thing should also apply to framework implementing JAX-RS, right ?

Comment: Again: this **IS NOT** part of JAX-WS. The framework implementing JAX-WS may provide this functionality or not.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the R :(. That's a different question and should be handled in a different post, but after a quick search, it also depends on implementation. You can even use CDI or Spring beans to support JAX-RS, so leveraging the scope of the bean to the framework rather than to JAX-RS implementation.